# C++ member function explicit template instantiation across DLL

Tags: c++, templates, dll, explicit-instantiation

I am creating a `DLL` in `C++` using `Visual Studio 2013` on `Windows 8.1 Update 1`.
There is a class called `XMLData` which has a public member function called `getAttribute`.

**XMLData.h**

```
namespace DDGL
{
    class DLL_EXPORTED XMLData
    {

       ...

       // const char* is used to avoid problems with trying to pass an
       // std::string over DLL boundaries
       template <typename Type> Type getAttribute (const char* attribute) const;

       ...

    };
}
```

Inside the DLL, every use is instantiated as you'd expect and works fine.

However, inside an application I will of course get undefined references for the `<typename Type>`'s that haven't been used within the DLL.

So, I try to use explicit template instantiation (I'd rather not put the implementation in header, for a learning exercise if anything):

**XMLData.cpp**

```
namespace DDGL
{

    ...

    // getAttribute definition

    ...

    template float XMLData::getAttribute(const char* attribute) const;

    ...

}
```

However, I still get an unresolved external in the application using the DLL:

**Output**

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall DDGL::XMLData::getAttribute<float>(char const *)const " (??$getAttribute@M@XMLData@DDGL@@QBEMPBD@Z) referenced in function "class std::shared_ptr<class DDGL::IGameObject> __cdecl SimpleExplodingRocketDeserialiser(class DDGL::XMLData)" (?SimpleExplodingRocketDeserialiser@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@VIGameObject@DDGL@@@std@@VXMLData@DDGL@@@Z)
```

**DLL_EXPORTED**

```
#ifdef DDGL_DLL_BUILDING
    #define DLL_EXPORTED __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORTED __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

---

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: An explicit instantiation could help you only if you use static linking (via *.lib files), not dynamic one (*.dll).

Comment: @Constructor Why on earth not?

Comment: Because templates is a compiler-time feature, not a run-time one.

Comment: @Constructor and DLLs are compiled?

Comment: Yes, but they are loaded at run time. You are trying to compile the main program without linking to it the code of your template instantiations.

Comment: @Constructor Aren't they linked like any other function in a DLL?

Comment: Yes, but the problem in the main program, isn't it?

Comment: @Constructor My point is, the purpose of explicit template instantiation is so things like this can be done. It is a compile time feature. I instantiate the required template in the DLL, but it cannot link against it in the application the uses the DLL.

Comment: I'm sorry I inattentively read your question. There is a syntax in Visual C++ to export template instantiations from a DLL. But you doesn't use it properly. I can't find a good article on this task in MSDN right now, but here is one which is close enough and can help you: ["How to export an instantiation of a Standard Template Library (STL) class and a class that contains a data member that is an STL object"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168958/en-us). It is about STL template classes but your case is similar to it.

Comment: @Constructor thank you :) So, looking at that article, it seems like I am not exporting the symbol for the instantiations, even though it is indeed being compiled within the DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that, whilst I was indeed explicitly instantiating the template correctly, I was not exporting the symbol for each instantiation.

The solution was to do the following:

```
namespace DDGL
{
    class DLL_EXPORTED XMLData
    {

       ...

       // const char* is used to avoid problems with trying to pass an
       // std::string over DLL boundaries
       template <typename Type> Type getAttribute (const char* attribute) const;

       ...

    };

    DLL_TEMPLATE_CLASS_MEMBER float XMLData::getAttribute(const char* attribute) const;
}
```

Where `DLL_TEMPLATE_CLASS_MEMBER` was defined as:

```
#ifdef DDGL_DLL_BUILDING
    #define DLL_TEMPLATE_CLASS_MEMBER template DLL_EXPORTED
#else
    #define DLL_TEMPLATE_CLASS_MEMBER extern template DLL_EXPORTED
#endif
```

Doing this correctly exported the symbols for the explicit template instantiation and allowed me to use them outside the DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Although @OMGtechy solution works, I think it's an overkill.
It's sufficient to specify `DLL_EXPORTED` for both the template declaration and template definition.

In the header file:

```
namespace DDGL
{
    class DLL_EXPORTED XMLData
    {
       template <typename Type> DLL_EXPORTED Type getAttribute (const char* attribute) const;

    };
}
```

In the .cpp file defining the function:

```
namespace DDGL
{
    template<> DLL_EXPORTED float XMLData::getAttribute(const char* attribute) const {
        // Function body goes here
    }
}
```

Tested on MSVC++2017 .

Some thoughts: I think it would be logical if `DLL_EXPORTED` on class definition worked on its template methods too. Non-templated methods do not require `DLL_EXPORTED` again on each method. So what's so different for template methods? I don't know for sure.